# WHERE Company = (DISTINCT Company)

Tags: mysql, distinct, where-clause

Hey i want to get few datarows out of a table. But don´t wanna have the companies doubled. so i wanted use the DISTINCT clause to reduce the companies. Is something like this possible?

```
SELECT Company, Firstname, Surname, eMail, Adress, Place, Phone, Fax FROM `contact_list` 
WHERE Company = (DISTINCT Company as `compName`)
```

FROM:

```
Company | Firstname | Surname | eMail             | Adress     | Place     | Phone   | Fax
DELL    | Max       | Master  | m.master@dell.com | dellstreet | chicago   | 543478  | 543267 
DELL    | John      | Doe     | j.doe@dell.com    | dellstreet | chicago   | 543462  | 543267 
SHELL   | Charlie   | Fame    | charlie@shell.com | nicestreet | shelltown | 5546546 | 54535
```

Expecting:

```
Company | Firstname | Surname | eMail             | Adress     | Place     | Phone   | Fax
DELL    | Max       | Master  | m.master@dell.com | dellstreet | chicago   | 543478  | 543267 
SHELL   | Charlie   | Fame    | charlie@shell.com | nicestreet | shelltown | 5546546 | 54535
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected output.

Comment: And change the title too..

Comment: What do column 1 and 10 contain?

Comment: offcourse you can use in this group by clause ....on the bases of company ....

Comment: Check the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) for the usage and meaning of `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `distinct` this way. Instead use `group by`:

```
SELECT column1, Company, - column10 FROM `contact_list` 
GROUP BY company
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this...

```
select distinct a, c from table_c
```

Or

```
select a, b from table_c group by a, b
```

group by will be more helpful if you want to use some aggregate function like count or sum...

```
  select a, b, count(*) from table_c group by a, b

  select a, b, sum(d) from table_c group by a, b
```

a and b represent to your column name ....

I hope this is working....

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you have a unique id in the table or a creation date or some way of identifying which row you want when there are duplicates.  If so:

```
select cl.*
from contact_list cl join
     (select cl.company, max(id) as maxid
      from contact_list
      group by cl.company
     ) ccl
     on cl.company = ccl.company and cl.id = ccl.maxid;
```

This returns the row with the maximum id.